# TinyMCE not appearing on custom form

Tags: 6, input-formats

I am creating a custom form and have run into a problem. I'm using the WYSIWYG module and for some reason the text areas  on this custom form don't show as rich text editors (tinymce shows on other parts of he site)

```
    $form['terms_format'][implode('~', array(MODULE_NAME, FIELD_TERMS))] = array(
    '#title'         => t('Terms and Conditions')
   ,'#type'          => 'textarea'
   ,'#description'   => t('Terms and conditiona')
   ,'#default_value' => variable_get(implode('~', array(MODULE_NAME, FIELD_TERMS)), "")
   ,'#required'      => TRUE
);
$form['terms_format']['format'] = filter_form(FILTER_FORMAT_DEFAULT);
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong? I'm using drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the format value `'format' => 'filtered_html'` to allow filtered html or '#format' => 'full_html'

```
$form['terms_format'][implode('~', array(MODULE_NAME, FIELD_TERMS))] = array(
    '#title'         => t('Terms and Conditions')
   ,'#type'          => 'textarea'
   ,'#description'   => t('Terms and conditiona')
   ,'#default_value' => variable_get(implode('~', array(MODULE_NAME, FIELD_TERMS)), "")
   ,'#required'      => TRUE
   'format' => 'filtered_html',
);
```

For drupal 6 try

```
if (!isset($edit['format'])) {
  $edit['format'] = FILTER_FORMAT_DEFAULT;
}
$form['terms_format']['format'] = filter_form($edit['format']);
```

Make sure your default filter format is filtered html or full html

Comment: does this work in drupal 6?

Comment: guess you just updated your question to say Drupal 6. See my updated answer

Comment: that code does the same as the snippet i posted above, I changed it to use your snippet and still no success.

Comment: What is your form called $form['terms_format'][] or $form['terms_format]? if it is $form['terms_format]['somethinghere] then it should be $form['terms_format']['something here']['format'] = filter_form(FILTER_FORMAT_DEFAULT);

Comment: my form is $form['terms_fieldset']['terms_format']['terms']['format'] = filter_form(FILTER_FORMAT_DEFAULT);